# Return Duplicated index of using Pivot function

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pivot

I create a dataframe from Yahoo and I want to use Pivot function to categorize the data. I want the index is Date, columns is symbol, value is close.

However, it returns an Value error. May I know anyone could tell me what is the problem?

The code like this:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime as dt

all_stock = pd.DataFrame()
list_2014 = ['VMC','MLM','NUE','MOS','TTWO','FB','NFLX','AAP','BKNG','UA','CMG','UAA','LEN','STZ','DVN','FANG','PXD','ICE','PRU','CNC','ALXN','INCY','ILMN','BIIB','DXCM','TMO','GILD','AAL','INFO','INFO','JCI','MAA','MCHP','PAYC','LRCX','QRVO','SWKS','FLT','ANET','MU']
start ='2010-10-30'
end = '2020-10-30'

for i in list_2014:
    df = web.DataReader(i,'yahoo',start,end)
    df['symbol'] = i
    all_stock = all_stock.append(df, ignore_index=False)
all_stock.head()

close_price = all_stock[['Close','symbol']].reset_index()
close_price.pivot('Date','symbol','Close')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct with a (small minor) problem: your pivot refuses to work because of a duplication of a symbol (with the same dates).

Check `list_2014` - you have 'INFO' twice. Simply remove one and re-run.

Comment: @janicewww pleasure!